# Was ist eine Kepse?

Tags: meaning

Ich hörte gerade ein Hörbuch, "Der Hexer und die Henkerstochter" von Oliver Pötzsch, dabei erklang der Satz:

> Das einzige, was störte, war dieser neunmalkluge Bader und seine verfluchte Kepse...

Was ist eine Kepse (oder Käpse oder anderes Homophon)? Mein einziger Fund ist bisher, [dieser](https://de.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060609012553AAPlMJU), aber in obigem Zusammenhang geht es eindeutig um die Gattin des Baders, also passt die Bedeutung "Heuhaufen" nicht.

Es dürfte sich, da die Erzählung in Bayern spielt, am ehesten um ein bayrisches Wort handeln.

Comment: Vielleicht Kebse? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kebse

Comment: @CarstenS Das ergäbe Sinn!

Comment: Heißt auch: Kebsfrau

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grimm's Wörterbuch hat noch einen Eintrag dazu:

> kebse, f. gleich kebsweib, ahd. chebis, chepis und chebisa, mhd. kebes und kebese, kebse, spä- ter kebisch Herbort 5507, käbisch Schottel 436a (mnd. kevesch Ssp. 1, 51, 2 var.), wahr- scheinlich auch kebsch, kebsche; mnd. keves, kevese, mnl. kefse, nnl. kevisse (bei Kil. auch kiese); ags. cifese, cefese und cefes, cifes, ceafes, cäbis, cives, engl. erloschen. das einfache kebse, nach der mhd. zeit von kebsweib verdrängt, und schon in den vocc. des 15. jh. fehlend, ist in neue- rer zeit in schriften wieder aufgefrischt worden (vgl.kämpe): kebsen und concubinen.

Im Prinzip also eine "Nebenfrau", oder wie im Eintrag zu *Kebsweib*:

> andere ausdrücke sind beischläferin, in gewählter schriftsprache, früher auch nebenweib, zuweib, beifrau, beiweib

Das Wort ist an sich nicht regional, nur praktisch ausgestorben: Auch in Luthers erster Bibelübersetzung taucht es auf, es dürfte sich also nicht um ein speziell bairisches Wort handeln:

> und Abraham gab all sein Gut Isaak, aber den Kindern, die er von den Kebsweibern hatte, gab er Geschenke.

Auch der [Online-Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kebse) hat noch einen Eintrag dazu, listet das Wort allerdings als "veraltet":

> Kebse: Nebenfrau, Konkubine